# Pattern for notifying Activity of a network status code

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have many Activities that have several fragments. Part of the work those fragments do is to make authenticated network calls. It is possible that the token will expire. When that happens, I will see the 401 in the networking layer. What is the preferred method to communicate back to up the stack to whichever fragment initiated the network activity that it needs to initiate the logoff procedure? In other words, when the networking layer gets a 401, I want to communicate that back to the UI that the user needs to be log offeven though many other Activities may have also been invoked since then. This is often done via custom exceptions being handled in the app but I was wondering if there was a specific pattern that was preferred other than that. Something using Live Data perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate in layers. Each layer should be responsible of a single task. There are many ways to do this, but you could use the MVVM Google approach which consists in:

- **M (Model)**: data classes and repositories that persist/retrieve them.
- **V (View)**: Activities/Fragments that observe data objects (LiveData) exposed by the VM and also call actions of the VM.
- **VM (ViewModel)**: Exposes actions, e.g. `login`, internally calls a Repository which calls the API (e.g. using Retrofit2), when it receives a result, it updates the data objects observed by the V.

Have a look at:

- [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
- [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
- [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html#8)

Comment: For your specific use case, you may have: A ViewModel that has a `login` method, that calls a repository that calls Retrofit to perform the actual network call. Activity should observe a LiveData. The next Activities/Fragments would have their corresponding ViewModels and will call methods that internally will call a Repository method that will perform a network call. Again, here you can observe a LiveData with a success result or a "401" state.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's already done...separation into those layers. I've edited the original question to make it more clear. Observing the 401 in the networking layer is done already. What I'm trying to do is make it so I don't have validation code in every model that checks for a 401 being returned.

Comment: Because all the services could return 401, then all of them should parse that response, maybe you could have a BaseModel.
If you need to communicate something to the user, then it's responsibility of the UI, you could implement this in a BaseActivity/Fragment so you don't have to repeat on each activity/fragment.